# Fetch Gallup data JSON page and convert to csv using R

Tags: json, r, csv, import

I would like to fetch json data in R from the following page and convert it to a tibble. First time working with json in R.

The following code doesn't work, so could use some help.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

trump_json <- fromJSON(txt = "http://news.gallup.com/wwwv7interactives/json/CURRENTPRESWEEKLY/codename.aspx?")
obama_json <- fromJSON(txt = "http://news.gallup.com/wwwv7interactives/json/OBAMAEXPANDED/codename.aspx?")

as.tibble(trump_json)
```

**EDIT**: changed file into txt argument.

Now it produces:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     `?xml` CurrentPresident
     <list>           <list>
1 <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>
2 <chr [1]>      <list [12]>
3 <chr [1]>       <list [2]>
```

Comment: The argument is named `txt` and not `file`.

Comment: Oh ofcourse... Do you know how to go on after the tibble result.

Comment: Check what data you got: `df1$CurrentPresident$data` and extract or save or ... (the tibble is saved in `df1`)

Answer (score 0):

You're question title doesn't match what you're asking for above. I would update the question title to reflect this when possible.

Kindly find this solution for converting the JSON data into a tibble in R.

```
library(jsonlite)

json_raw <- stream_in(url("http://news.gallup.com/wwwv7interactives/json/CURRENTPRESWEEKLY/codename.aspx?"), flatten = TRUE)

#--str(json_raw)

json_flat <- flatten(json_raw)

#--json_flat

library(tibble)

json_tibble <- as_data_frame(json_flat)

json_tibble
```